# Cast generic list form DerivedClass to BaseClass

Tags: c#

I've these two classes

```
public class A {}
public class B : A {}
```

And the cast from class `A` to class `B` works fine.

```
B testB1 = new B();
A testA1 = testB1;
B testB2 = (B)testA1; //this works
```

But: Why is this cast not working?

```
List<B> testB1List = new List<B>();
List<A> testA1List = ((IEnumerable<A>)testB1List).ToList();
List<B> testB2List = ((IEnumerable<B>)testA1List).ToList(); //not working
```

The solution is:

```
List<B> testB1List = new List<B>();
List<A> testA1List = ((IEnumerable<A>)testB1List).ToList();
List<B> testB2List = testA1List.Cast<B>().ToList();
```

But why is it like this?

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith not really. I don't understand the different between IEnumerable<B> cast (not working) and  testA1ListCast<B>().

Comment: As always, it would help if you'd specify exactly what happened, instead of just "not working". But fundamentally, a `List<A>` *is not* an `IEnumerable<B>`, even if it happens to contain references to `B` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the Cast extension method casts each member of the list to the specified type so in your example it can then be assigned as a `List<B>` because all list members have been cast to B.

But in the first example, you are casting the IEnumerable itself, not the members of the list:

```
(IEnumerable<B>)testA1List
```

So it fails because it is trying to cast `List<A>` to `IEnumerable<B>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I get it.